# Setting global Button and EditText objects

Tags: android, global-variables

I'm getting null pointer exceptions when I try to initialize Button and EditText objects in global scope, can't figure it out.  I've commented out everything but the bare minimum for the app to display my layout, but this still causes a crash:

```
private EditText addmoney = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.addmoney);
```

R.id.addmoney definitely, definitely exists.  So what the heck?  Is it impossible to declare EditText in global scope?  I need to be able to call it from both onCreate and onPause in a class extending Activity, is there maybe another way I should be doing this?

EDIT:

I tried using shade's method of inflating the layout first but it causes errors, apparently your not allowed to use system services before onCreate() has been called and inflating a view requires one.

Comment: The content view (xml) you set in your activity via setContentView needs to hold the EditText element R.id.addmoney.
Can you paste the code of your activity where you set the content view. And also the relevant xml layout maybe.

Comment: For my method to work, you need a Context that is alive. Your context becomes alive after you call super.onCreate (Bundle). Btw, you can use any context (from any activity), or the ApplicationContext, as long as they are alive and active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you could do something like this:

```
private View dummy = (View) View.inflate(this, R.layout.dummy, null);
private EditText addmoney = (EditText) dummy.findViewById(R.id.addmoney);
```

... and in the onCreate (or wherever else):

```
setContentView (dummy);
```

Since you already have the parent of the EditText view instantiated, you can reference it without having a NPE.

**NOTE**: The first parameter of *inflate* is a **Context**. Therefore, you need a Context that is alive for this to work.

- Ooops, wrong class :D

Answer (score 3):

You have to execute `findViewById` only after you have set the content for your current activity.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);
    addmoney = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.addmoney);//it knows in which file to search for the id
}
```

Comment: Exactly, this is because the activity needs to know which `R.id.addmoney` element it should use. Potentially the same element with the same id might exist in some other layout. This is why the `setContentview(...)` has to be invoked first.

Comment: @Juri: It's actually simpler than that. `findViewById` performs a simple tree traversal across your view hierarchy. If there's no view hierarchy there's not only nothing to find, there's nowhere to begin the traversal.